# Isotope with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I'm using a filtered portfolio on my homepage. I implemented isotope with a little tutorial but I'm unable to combine it with infinite scrolling.

For isotope I'm using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var $container = jQuery('.fix-portfolio .items');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector: ".pagination",
nextSelector: ".pagination a[rel=next]",
itemSelector: ".item",
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more items to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
    }
}, function (newElements) {
$container.isotope('appended', $(newElements));
});


jQuery(window).on('resize', function () {
    jQuery('.fix-portfolio .items').isotope('reLayout')
});
```

The plugin is loaded and there are no errors displayed in my console. Could it be a problem that I'm loading it for a custom query?

```
if ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();
endwhile;else :endif;wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

I hope I was able to explaine what I did in a more detailed way. I'm also confused why I need to define navigation selectors as I thought the page is loading automatically, when I scroll to the end of the container (sorry, as I already mentioned, I'm a total js newby).
Thanks for your help!
regards, Cara

Comment: You need to provide more information for us to be able to help. How is your infinite scroll working? What's the structure look like? What are you having trouble with in particular?

Comment: Sorry, for my quite incomplete request. I was researching for isotope and infinite scroll and found hundreds of different solutions and tutorials that have been quite confusing for me, as I'm just about to do my first steps in js. Those basic infos of ndiego already gave me a good direction to start.

Comment: So I tried @ndiegos method and it again didn't work. I hope it's ok, when I edit my first post above and try to explain in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite scrolling is possible with Isotope, but without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell  where the problem with your code lies. If you are looking for information on how to implement infinite scrolling with Isotope, check out this link: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/infinite-scroll.html.

In order for infinite scrolling to work with Isotope, you need to be using the [append](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/methods.html#appended) method to display the additional posts in combination with something like the [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) plugin by Paul Irish. This particular plugin is mentioned by David DeSandro, the developer of Isotope.

Comment: Please provide some information that the links provide and not just the links. If those sites go down we'd like for your answer to still be useful